# JS pass variable to event

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

Soo... I'm working on a Telegram Bot for Node.JS, after a user joined, my bot will welcome them:

```
function Welcome(e)
{
  console.log("Neuer Member");
  console.log(e); //Das ist der, der joint
  let markup = Extra.markup(
    Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.callbackButton('I read the rules and accept them!', 'AcceptRules'),
      Markup.urlButton('Read the rules here', 'https://t.me/MyBot')
    ])
  );
  bot.telegram.restrictChatMember(e.chat.id, e.from.id, {can_send_messages: false, can_send_media_messages: false, can_send_other_messages: false});
  e.reply(`Welcome to the chat @${e.message.from.username}, please make sure to read the rules https://t.me/MyBot\n\nYou will be able to chat in here once you read them :3\n\n If you have trouble you can use this button right here to accept AFTER you read them ;3`, markup, Extra.inReplyTo(e.update.message.message_id))
}
```

[The message when the User joins the chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1mGd.png)

After the user joined the chat, the can click on the left button attached to the message, to the Callback.Button, which triggers this function:

```
bot.action('AcceptRules', e => {
  //if(e.update.callback_query.from.username == )
  let markup = Extra.markup(
    Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.urlButton('Read the rules here', 'https://t.me/VenWaifuBot')
    ])
  );
  //Das ist der, der akzeptiert
  allow(e);
  e.editMessageText(`✅Thank you ${e.update.callback_query.from.first_name} for reading the rules! I hope you have fun here ;3\n\nYou can always read the rules here, they will be updates from time to time`, markup);
  console.warn(e);
});
```

So my question is... how can I be sure that ONLY the person who joined --> User triggers Welcome(e) funciton when joining --> Username is in local e variable

e.update.message.from.username from the user who joined

e.update.callback_query.from.username is the user who clicked on the button

But both are local variables...

How can I pass that variable from the Welcome Message to the bot.action Event?

I thoght about making a temporary global memory which stores the username, but what if another user joins in the time and interferes... making an array also seems a bit off... anyone has a solution?

Sincerly
Ven

Comment: Just to clarify, you are wanting to send the event itself and some other variable to a function? Something that seems like it should be called liked this: myfunction(e, somethingelse)? I know that doesn't work, but is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

A [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) would be a natural way to do this.

At the top level:

```
const usersWhoNeedToAcceptRules = new Set();
```

In Welcome:

```
usersWhoNeedToAcceptRules.add(e.message.from.username);
```

In your callback:

```
if (usersWhoNeedToAcceptRules.has(e.update.callback_query.from.username)) {
    usersWhoNeedToAcceptRules.remove(e.update.callback_query.from.username);
    ...
```